# How to pass router props in a Modal/Dialog in React for navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am stuck on a problem. I have added a login component in my React-Project. That login module is in a modal/dialog form. Login component button resides in Header component of the project. As usual i am not setting a router path for this login module and so i am not able to set the props. I don't want to move login component in a separate as thats the requirement. So how should i get `history props` to check the page route

Part of Header component that opens up the login dialog window

```
{
  this.state.sessionValid ? (
    <div className="flex">
      <Button edge="end" color="inherit" onClick={this.openLogin.bind(this)}>
        Login
      </Button>
      <Button edge="end" color="inherit" onClick={this.openSignup.bind(this)}>
        Signup
      </Button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Button edge="end" color="inherit">
        Logout
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={this.props.openLogin}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={this.props.closeLogin}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogContent style={{ padding: 50 }}>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt="Image for signup"
              style={{ width: "30%", borderRadius: 5 }}
              image="logo.png"
              title="Front"
            />
          </div>

          <form style={{ marginTop: 0 }} onSubmit={this.submit.bind(this)}>
            <div>
              <TextField
                fullWidth={true}
                required={true}
                label="Email"
                value={this.state.formData.email}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "email")}
                margin="normal"
              />
            </div>

            <Button color="primary" type="submit" disabled={this.formCheck()}>
              Login
            </Button>

            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.props.openSignupInstead}>
              Signup
            </Button>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Part of Router function.

```
return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <header className="mainHeader">
          <HeaderComponent />
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dirty way

You can pass history as props of your `<HeaderComponent />`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
...
export default function main() {
    ...
    return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter history={history>
        <header className="mainHeader">
          <HeaderComponent history={history} />
        </header>
}
```

I used this technic many times, works like a charm but get really messy and  difficult to maintain.

## React Hooks: useRouter

Since [react 16.8 introduced hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), you can use that to define your component, and then use the [react router useRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6430) hook anywhere to access your router and access history.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const RouterContext = React.createContext(null);

export const HookedBrowserRouter = ({ children, history }) => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route>
      {routeProps => (
        <RouterContext.Provider value={routeProps}>
          {children}
        </RouterContext.Provider>
      )}
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

export function useRouter() {
  return React.useContext(RouterContext);
}
```

Replace your `<BrowserRouter>` with `<HookedBrowserRouter history={history}>` you just defined

Then in any component using react hooks:

```
import { useRouter } from "../router";

export default function YourComponent() {
  const { history } = useRouter();
  // Do something with history
  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: Just trying to implement it now. Its actually complicated compared to ones. I was trying to  pass history as props in `<HeaderComponent />` (which is present in App.js outside the src folder), and compiler is no accepting `const { history } = useRouter()` . Can you do me a favor and tell what `history` you are passing in header component.

Comment: I create history from `history` package, updated my answer with proper code .

Comment: Also i have no idea why did u go through this pain. Publishing the answer below :)

Answer (score -1):

Login component is shown by clicking on a button on header component. So here i am using window's location feature to work. I am providing an overview of this, so that you may get a little idea.

```
export default class HeaderComponent extends Component {
   .
   .
submitLogin = () =>{
    window.location.href= '/'
 }
   .
   .

render() {
   return (
    <div>
   .
   .
<LoginComponent
    openLogin={this.state.openLogin}
    closeLogin={this.closeLogin.bind(this)}
    openSignupInstead={this.openSignupInstead.bind(this)}
    submitLogin={this.submitLogin.bind(this)} />
   .
   .
 </div>
)}}
```

Comment: I would not recommand going against HTML5 History API, what if someone try to use your code with a router configured using hashed URL ? Might be fine for your specific case, but best practice is to keep maximum compatibilty which is why people defined a [History_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and builded a full library like [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to make it easy to implement.

Comment: React itself does not have a built-in routing solution. So library uses the exact same feature provided by browser's`window.location` by wrapping it around in react code. Beside what you have done is not user friendly even you know this. Our code should be user friendly to even for those who take over the project in future you must know. Also i can assure you the behaviour is 100% same of `window.location.href ='/someroute'` Just that this `someroute` should be provided by you in `BroswerRouter`, however if there is need to pass params, you will need `this.props`, thats where its required.

Comment: And my question have only this answer, none others.